# How to manage cookies when GPO prevents history delete

Tags: browser, windows-server-2008-r2, history, internet-explorer-9

I've disabled history deletion in the default GPO.  Works great.  However, now when I have a user who *does* nees to clear cookies (buggy website), I can't figure out how to clear them.  Is there a utility that I've missed? Or should I just go to the directory and delete them manually?

Comment: Wow.  I've either stumped the community, or I haven't posted a clear / interesting enough question.  I have full system and domain admin access and the only way I can see to clear them is to delete the TempInet directories.  I hate to blow out the whole cache if I don't have to...

Comment: For the time being, I've just removed the GPO setting.  Now anyone can clear their history without intervention, and inappropriate browsing will go on as usual.